# XUnit code coverage results different on CI build compared to locally

Tags: .net, code-coverage, xunit, bamboo, coverlet

I'm presently baffled by the same command, on the same code, with the same `dotnet` version, producing two different results. My development machine is an ARM-based Mac, and CI is in a Docker image run from Bamboo on a CentOS host.

### Test coverage command

```
dotnet test --filter Category!=LocalOnly --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

### Dockerfile for build plan

*The Python installation is because I'm using pycobertura to analyze the coverage results*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

WORKDIR /app

ENV HOME="/home"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip install pycobertura
RUN pip install requests

RUN dotnet --version
```

### Version numbers

- dotnet: 7.0.304
- xunit: 2.4.2
- coverlet.collector: 6.0.0

For the one file with partial coverage, the reported line coverage drops from 100% (Mac) to 66.67% (CI), and the branch coverage drops from 75% (Mac) to 0.00% (CI).

What should I do in order to figure out what's going on? To be clear, it's tough to say either environment is right/wrong at this point, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, and my build plan verifies coverage level, so I'm stuck for now. Could it be an ARM/x64 difference somehow? That doesn't seem likely.